# Creating PCoA Plots in R with given UniFrac distance matrix

Tags: r, distance

I have a distance matrix (weighted UniFrac distances) and I want to perform PCoA Analysis in R.

distance matrix:

[image: Distance matrix imported in R]

I tried some code I found online:

```
beta <- read.table('weighted_unifrac.txt', sep = "\t", head = T, row=1)
pc.beta <- cmdscale (beta, k=2)
plot(pc.beta [,1], pc.beta[,2])
```

It gives me a plot:

[image: Plot]

However is there a possibility to color now different groups of my sample. 
Any tips how I would link the distance matrix with my data about the groups?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to change graphics engine to ggplot2, where

```
df<-data.frame(x <- rnorm(10, 10, 1), y <- rnorm(10, 10, 2))

ggplot(df, aes(x = c(1:length(df$x)))) +
  geom_point(aes(y = df$y, colour = 'y')) +
  geom_point(aes(y = df$x, colour = 'x')) +
  labs(x = 'Index [1, 10]', y = 'Values')
```

produces the plot

[image]